# extract public key from Certificate Signing Request

Tags: certificates, python

Hi is there a way where we can extract public key from certificate signing request ? if so can this be done using python3 ? here is the sample csr from https://www.digicert.com/order/sample-csr.php as an example. I have some POC regarding this, please let me know the steps of extracting public key from CSR, or do I need to provide more information.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Comment: No, that's not how a CSR works. The public key is obtained from the issuing CA once it approves the CSR.

Comment: @user2320464: no. The public key is part of the CSR.

Comment: RFC2986 does indicate the inclusion of a public key. I doubt OP has that level of knowledge and thus should know the "useful" public key is issued by a CA.

Answer (score 2):

`openssl req -in foo.csr -pubkey -noout` gives you directly the public key as PEM:

```
$ openssl req -in foo.csr -pubkey -noout
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8+To7d+2kPWeBv/orU3L
VbJwDrSQbeKamCmowp5bqDxIwV20zqRb7APUOKYoVEFFOEQs6T6gImnIolhbiH6m
4zgZ/CPvWBOkZc+c1Po2EmvBz+AD5sBdT5kzGQA6NbWyZGldxRthNLOs1efOhdnW
FuhI162qmcflgpiIWDuwq4C9f+YkeJhNn9dF5+owm8cOQmDrV8NNdiTqin8q3qYA
HHJRW28glJUCZkTZwIaSR6crBQ8TbYNE0dc+Caa3DOIkz1EOsHWzTx+n0zKfqcbg
Xi4DJx+C1bjptYPRBPZL8DAeWuA8ebudVT44yEp82G96/Ggcf7F33xMxe0yc+Xa6
owIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

> if so can this be done using python3

The cryptography package offers the necessary functionality, like loading a CSR and [getting the public key](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.CertificateSigningRequest.public_key). But this is actually a programming question, i.e. off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use openssl to show the information in a CSR, including the public key.  I saved your CSR to a file csr.txt, then ran the following command:

```
openssl req -in csr.txt -noout -text
```

This produced:

```
Certificate Request:
Data:
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Subject: C = US, ST = Utah, L = Lindon, O = DigiCert Inc., OU = DigiCert, CN = example.digicert.com
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
            Modulus:
                00:f3:e4:e8:ed:df:b6:90:f5:9e:06:ff:e8:ad:4d:
                cb:55:b2:70:0e:b4:90:6d:e2:9a:98:29:a8:c2:9e:
                5b:a8:3c:48:c1:5d:b4:ce:a4:5b:ec:03:d4:38:a6:
                28:54:41:45:38:44:2c:e9:3e:a0:22:69:c8:a2:58:
                5b:88:7e:a6:e3:38:19:fc:23:ef:58:13:a4:65:cf:
                9c:d4:fa:36:12:6b:c1:cf:e0:03:e6:c0:5d:4f:99:
                33:19:00:3a:35:b5:b2:64:69:5d:c5:1b:61:34:b3:
                ac:d5:e7:ce:85:d9:d6:16:e8:48:d7:ad:aa:99:c7:
                e5:82:98:88:58:3b:b0:ab:80:bd:7f:e6:24:78:98:
                4d:9f:d7:45:e7:ea:30:9b:c7:0e:42:60:eb:57:c3:
                4d:76:24:ea:8a:7f:2a:de:a6:00:1c:72:51:5b:6f:
                20:94:95:02:66:44:d9:c0:86:92:47:a7:2b:05:0f:
                13:6d:83:44:d1:d7:3e:09:a6:b7:0c:e2:24:cf:51:
                0e:b0:75:b3:4f:1f:a7:d3:32:9f:a9:c6:e0:5e:2e:
                03:27:1f:82:d5:b8:e9:b5:83:d1:04:f6:4b:f0:30:
                1e:5a:e0:3c:79:bb:9d:55:3e:38:c8:4a:7c:d8:6f:
                7a:fc:68:1c:7f:b1:77:df:13:31:7b:4c:9c:f9:76:
                ba:a3
            Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Attributes:
        a0:00
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
     1d:24:72:b1:5c:71:29:85:0e:6c:68:c7:43:5e:d3:55:08:a9:
     2b:03:a8:78:0b:f9:79:87:4d:72:70:ad:ee:83:84:94:99:c1:
     bb:c4:b4:e2:b4:1b:7f:9d:af:81:6c:d7:55:ae:50:db:79:a9:
     c2:ec:c7:96:bc:ba:4e:06:e8:02:87:33:3b:a1:2e:c2:7b:5d:
     98:e0:99:05:c6:10:2a:58:43:89:82:df:24:f7:66:80:86:a4:
     85:db:c3:e8:8f:de:59:84:11:78:1a:40:bd:13:c7:92:c5:97:
     fa:24:29:b2:98:c0:8a:8d:8b:22:96:38:c8:fb:65:1f:f0:c5:
     68:3f:64:31:91:b3:9e:71:ba:87:8b:0c:9f:d9:44:57:fd:6c:
     8f:88:68:25:1d:d5:8a:df:61:c1:c8:97:71:bc:ec:0b:fe:af:
     8f:58:57:0a:91:0d:3d:15:0d:5e:ee:2e:0a:a7:db:d5:c8:d4:
     fa:55:50:d0:8f:40:69:fd:a7:f7:97:e9:0a:3b:be:90:da:3f:
     26:d1:b4:0d:91:ed:72:ca:8d:06:85:f6:85:d6:78:25:2a:cb:
     58:6f:25:a7:3d:40:53:b6:f7:b3:9b:d5:a9:69:1c:fa:19:ee:
     65:a2:12:e2:70:8c:13:e2:8b:a6:bd:33:d1:b7:d2:75:28:df:
     d9:41:8b:5c
```

Comment: ok what section of the following output is public key,  is it `Subject Public Key Info:` ?

Comment: It's RSA, so the public key consists of the modulus and the exponent.

Comment: ok also is it possible that, `Modulus:` and `Exponent:` are same for a different certificates issued by the same source ?

Comment: It's common in RSA to have 65537 as the exponent.  But, the modulus is the product of the two large primes which make up the private key.  So, the modulus should be unique for each public key.  See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18031/how-to-find-modulus-from-a-rsa-public-key for more info.

Comment: so if I understand it that modulus should be unique for each public key, can we determine that CertA and CertB was issued from the same source ? does comparing `Subject:` of two diff cert issued by the same source is a good test ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'same source'?  Do you mean that CertA and CertB were issued by the same CA?  Or, do you mean that CertA and CertB secure the same site?

Comment: Oh Sorry  I was not clear, I meant same CA.

Comment: You only posted the CSR (certificate signing request).  There is no information about a CA in the CSR.  The CSR gets submitted to the CA, for the CA to sign, then the certificate (created by the CA, using info from the CSR, and signed by the CA) is used to secure the site.  So, the certificate will contain info about the CA, but the CSR will not.  The site(s) that the certificate will be used to secure appear in the Subject field (and Subject Alternative Name field) of the CSR.  The example CSR you posted is confusing, because the Subject is example.digicert.com, and digicert.com is also a CA.